# Move out <div/> from overflow: scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to implement next image(attached), the problem is when I do "overflow: scroll" it cuts all content after it. The main thing it's triangle after the scroll that moves with selected list item.

Any ideas with css/js? ?Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: without the code is hard to answer... but i guess you have a container div that wraps also the triangle. Apply overflow property to that div!

Comment: also the close of div is like this </div> not <div/>

Comment: @Lelio Faieta I need that scroll will be from the right side of triangle

Comment: @mlegg thanks, missed